# Radiobuttons are not showing in acrobat reader

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am creating a pdf with fillable form with itextsharp.
everything works peachy in foxit-reader, inline-pdf of chrome, except acrobat reader XI.

The thing is, i am creating a table with a cell where inside there is a table with a couple of columns.
every column has an cellevent to create a checkbox (radiobutton-special)

this will actually act like a radiobutton-group, but sadly not in acrobat-reader where I only see 1 checkbox

Main class, where the test is being called and pdf is written to filesystem:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] arrBytes;

            TestSimple ts = new TestSimple();
            ts.CreatePDF(out arrBytes);

            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Kaas\\Foo.pdf", arrBytes); 
        }
    }
```

TestClass where the Document is created and the checkboxes added

```
public class TestSimple
{
    public TestSimple() { }

    public void CreatePDF(out byte[] ssPdf)
    {
        ssPdf = new byte[] { };
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // step 1
            // document will be of A4 with margins
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 50, 50);
            // step 2
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(CreateSimpleTable());
            document.Close();
            ssPdf = ms.ToArray();

        }
    }

    private PdfPTable CreateSimpleTable()
    {
        PdfPCell cell;
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
        {
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row " + row));
            table.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column" + row));
            cell.PaddingLeft = 25f;
            cell.CellEvent = new RadioCheckBox("radiogroup", "check" + row);
            //checkbox
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

The CellEvent-class to create the checkboxes in the cells.

```
 public class RadioCheckBox : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        private string fieldName;
        private string onValue;

        private int boxSize = 12;
        private BaseColor backgroundColor = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
        private BaseColor borderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 00);

        public RadioCheckBox(string fieldName, string onValue)
        {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.onValue = onValue;
        }

        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {
            PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].PdfWriter;

            PdfAppearance[] onOff = new PdfAppearance[2];
            onOff[0] = canvases[0].CreateAppearance(boxSize, boxSize);
            onOff[0].SetColorFill(backgroundColor);
            onOff[0].SetColorStroke(borderColor);
            onOff[0].Rectangle(1, 1, boxSize - 1, boxSize - 1);
            onOff[0].FillStroke();
            onOff[1] = canvases[0].CreateAppearance(boxSize, boxSize);
            onOff[1].SetColorFill(backgroundColor);
            onOff[1].SetColorStroke(borderColor);
            onOff[1].Rectangle(1, 1, boxSize - 1, boxSize - 1);
            onOff[1].FillStroke();
            onOff[1].SetColorStroke(new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
            onOff[1].MoveTo(1, 1);
            onOff[1].LineTo(boxSize, boxSize);
            onOff[1].MoveTo(1, boxSize);
            onOff[1].LineTo(boxSize, 1);
            onOff[1].Stroke();

            //make it small rectangle
            Rectangle CheckboxRectangle = new Rectangle(rectangle);
            CheckboxRectangle.Right = CheckboxRectangle.Left + boxSize;
            CheckboxRectangle.Top = CheckboxRectangle.Bottom + boxSize;

            RadioCheckField bt = new RadioCheckField(writer, CheckboxRectangle, null, "Yes");
            bt.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CROSS;
            bt.Checked = false;
            bt.FontSize = 9;
            bt.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

            PdfFormField field = bt.CheckField;
            field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "No", onOff[0]);
            field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Yes", onOff[1]);

            PdfFormField pff = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(writer, false);
            pff.FieldName = fieldName;
            pff.AddKid(field);
            writer.AddAnnotation(pff);
        }
    }
```

this piece of code will get called a couple of times in a for-loop when creating the cells
what am i missing or doing wrong with it so it does not work in acrobat-reader, but it does work in foxit, chrome-inline reader?

example pdf: http://www.filedropper.com/foo

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF? (I'm using iText, not iTextSharp, and so cannot run your code directly. If there is an actual error in the generated PDF, fixing for iTextSharp should be similar to fixing for iText.)

Comment: here you go http://www.filedropper.com/foo

Comment: Ok, first of all: all `RadioCheckField`s in the same radio button group are expected to be kids of the same radio button, but you give each `RadioCheckField` its own radio button instance. That probably isn't the only problem, though.

Comment: I kinda figured that already, but I am at a loss how to combine those radiobutton with the event-mechanism provided

Comment: *I am at a loss how to combine those radiobutton with the event-mechanism provided* - that's easy. Create and initialize the radio button group `pff` only once outside the event, e.g. at the start of `CreateSimpleTable`, and forward it as constructor parameter to the event object. The cell layout event can then add the new radio button `field` as kid to the single radio buton group.

Comment: i tried that, but did not work for some reason. I will try some more later